# Postgres: Get owner of all schemas

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema, owner

I want to find out what the owner is of my postgres database schema. I tried

```
select * from information_schema.schemata s order by schema_name
```

But when I use a visual database client for our postgres database, there appear to be more schemas than the results of the query above. How can I see owners of these 'hidden' tables? I suspect it has something to do with the owner of the schema not granting others to see the schema, but I just can't figure that out.

Comment: Try `select * from pg_namespace`

Answer (score 4):

try:

```sql
SELECT
    r.rolname AS schema_owner,
    ns.*
FROM
    pg_namespace ns
JOIN
    pg_roles r 
ON
    ns.nspowner = r.oid;
```